# Save javascript image

Tags: browser, html, website, javascript

My daughter's school is posting nice pictures of her but unfortunately it is not possible to save them as they are displayed using javascript (right click on image then "save as..." only saves the html page).

I tried a web copier (WinHTTrack) which didn't succeed.

Any idea how to copy those images (without doing a cumbersome printscreen as there are hundreds of images)?

Website can be found here: http://www.vbssterrebeek.be/category/afbeeldingenalbums/kleuters/k1b/pingu

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firefox with [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) extension. Open that webpage then right-click anywhere on it and select DownThemAll!

Here is what you will see:

[image]

As you can see all the images have been selected automatically based on the filter. Don't go to **Pictures and Media** tab because there you will have only thumbnails.